# is there an index to be accessed in the CI foreach with {}-Notation?

Tags: codeigniter, notation

i'm new with Codeigniter,and whish to know if i can access any kind of iterator for the foreach with {}-Notation in my views.

The thing is, i'm having a list which should be devided after each x items.

example (what i would like to do:

```
<ul>
{list}
    <li>{items}</li>
    <? if ($iterator % 15 == 0) echo "</ul><ul>"; ?>
{/list}
</ul>
```

thanks in advice ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using codeigniters [template parser class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html), I don't think there is a way to do what you're looking for.

You could forego the template parser, and use a regular for loop:

```
<ul>
<?php
$i=1;
foreach($item as $key=>$value){
    echo "<li>".$value."</li>";
    if($i % 15 === 0) echo "</ul><ul>";
    $i++;
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: +1 the only way i can see is to use an additional counter as stromdrain has done, though i might possibly initialise it to 1 to begin with.

Comment: for sure, this works, but the question was to find a way for the other notation ;-)

Comment: I suppose you could modify the template parser class, but then all of your lists (or anything else run through the class) will have the `"</ul><ul>"`. So, in essence, it's not doable with the `{}` notation.

Comment: i see, there is no way of doing so with the desired notation ... well thanks for your help!